# Large chunk of data, trying to replace delimiter character in one column but not all delimiter characters

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataset, large-data

I'm trying to analyse a dataset (200mb, ~3mil lines) with Pandas, but this dataset contains one column filled by random users where all characters are allowed. This creates the problem that the delimiter character (\t) is also often found in the last column. In GVIM I tried searching and replacing all '\t's with ':'s, but this also replaces the actual delimiters (which are not shown in GVIM). Does anyone have tips as to how to specifically replace a character in a certain column in a large dataset?

E.g. the file I have uses tab (\t) as delimiter for its columns. However, there's a row with the following info:

```
137179101   genericname 431 499 19568   0   26 Apr 2010 01:45:05 GMT    Oakland,\   CA
```

Which messes up my Pandas notebook, because it expects 8 fields but gets 9 due to the tab between \ and CA. The 8th column is the only place where its actually possible to fill in your own tabs. So how do I change the "\t"s in ONLY the eighth column?

Thanks in advance!

Note that I have zero experience with Python scripting which I presume could solve it, but a faster approach than learning Python would be nice.

Comment: Hmmm, I think you need preprocessing `csv` by the number of `delimiters` in one row to new csv and then use `read_csv`.

Comment: How would I do this? I can't find any functions for it in Pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can first create DataFrame by [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with `sep='₩'` and then use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with parameter `n=7`, because you need split by first `7` separators only:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""137179101   genericname 431 499 19568   0   26 Apr 2010 01:45:05 GMT    Oakland,\   CA
137179101   genericname 431 499 19568   0   26 Apr 2010 01:45:05 GMT    Oakland,\   CA
137179101   genericname 431 499 19568   0   26 Apr 2010 01:45:05 GMT    Oakland,\   CA"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to Location
df  = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep="₩", header=None, names=['data'], encoding='Latin-1')

with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', -1):
    print df 
                                                                                     data
0  137179101   genericname 431 499 19568   0   26 Apr 2010 01:45:05 GMT    Oakland,\   CA
1  137179101   genericname 431 499 19568   0   26 Apr 2010 01:45:05 GMT    Oakland,\   CA
2  137179101   genericname 431 499 19568   0   26 Apr 2010 01:45:05 GMT    Oakland,\   CA   

print df.data.str.split('\t',n=7).apply(pd.Series)
           0            1    2    3      4  5                         6  \
0  137179101  genericname  431  499  19568  0  26 Apr 2010 01:45:05 GMT   
1  137179101  genericname  431  499  19568  0  26 Apr 2010 01:45:05 GMT   
2  137179101  genericname  431  499  19568  0  26 Apr 2010 01:45:05 GMT   
3  137179101  genericname  431  499  19568  0  26 Apr 2010 01:45:05 GMT   

               7  
0    Oakland,\CA  
1    Oakland,\CA  
2  Oakland,\\tCA  
3        Oakland
```

Comment: Hey man, I'm trying to use your solution, but I'm not sure how to properly use the command. I was importing my file through `df = pd.read_csv(Location, header=None, sep='\t', encoding='Latin-1', nrows=1000)` but I'm not really sure how to combine that with your given solution. I'm sorry if this is a very simple command but I'm very new to all of this.

Comment: Hmm, I think you cannot use `read_csv`, because output will be more as 8 columns - some separators can be in last 8. column. So I think you read all 8 column to one - `df = pd.read_csv(Location, header=None, sep='~', encoding='Latin-1', nrows=1000)` and then split this one column to 8 desired.

Comment: But you can read_csv? There is no `CParserError: Error tokenizing data.` ?

Comment: No I can't (I am getting the CParserError), so I'd need to convert the table before putting it through csv_read, but I don't know how to import the table aside from that. Given the Location variable, how should I use your command? `print df.data.str.split('\t',n=7).apply(pd.Location)`?

Comment: Yes, is there some chr like `|` or `~` or `°`, that is not in csv? If yes, you can use it as separator and read csv to one big column - I think `df = pd.read_csv(Location, header=None, sep='~', encoding='Latin-1', nrows=1000)`. Then you can use my solution.

Comment: But if I want to use `°` as seperator, I'd need to replace all my `\t`s with it, but how do I not replace the `\t`'s that are in the 8th column?

Comment: You have to use `°` as separator for NOT spliting column in read_csv. You can use my solution for splitting.

Comment: I'm sorry man, I don't understand. If I use `df = pd.read_csv(Location, header=None, sep='~', encoding='Latin-1', nrows=1000)` I get `Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 97, saw 2`, and then I can't use it for your first solution. If I use `print(df.data.str.split('\t',n=7).apply(pd.Location))`, I get `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'data'`. Could you type the commands (just the commands) you think I need?

Comment: Ok. First you need create dataframe by read_csv. Is it posibble? If yes, how?

Comment: No I can't, it gives me `CParserError: Error tokenizing data `

Comment: If you try separator €,@,^,¥,~, ₩ or ° still error?

Comment: Then it gives `Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 97, saw 2` because those delimiters are not actually inside of my .csv

Comment: No this is opposite problem. This separators are present in dataframe, so read_csv wants to separate data and it is impossible. Each separator return `Error tokenizing data. C error` ?

Comment: Ah, no, ₩ returned a huge column

Comment: Alright, I'm going to test it tomorrow, I'll accept as soon as I know if it works! Thanks for the effort mate, really really appreciate it

Comment: After my laptop was calculating for 20 minutes and eventually crashed, I tried it with a sample size 10000 and it worked! Thanks man!